# Symfony Forms: How can I add new items to a collection without posting the existing collection in my request

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity with a one-to-many relationship to any number of change-log entities. I'd like to be able to post the changes to the parent entity along with a log entry to be added to the log entries collection. I'm wondering about the best way to send a new log entry along with the change-set to the parent entity's form without passing the existing log entries back and forth, and without overwriting existing entries.

I've tried various options, but no matter how I configure the form, when I submit a single log entry along with my changes to the parent, the new log entry overwrites the first of the existing entries.

My present work-around is to set `mapped => false` in the log entry form field and, in the controller, to submit the log entry to its own form to populate a `new LogEntry` entity, then call the parent's `addLogEntry($logEntry)` method. I'd prefer if I could handle all of the logic in the parent entity's form, but I haven't found a way to do this.

Is there a tidier way to accomplish this?

Here's an example request:

```
{"subscriptions":
    {
        "status": "2",
        "logEntries":[
            {"eventType":"cancel",
            "reason":"testing",
            "origin": "telephone",
            "notes":"test test test"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but it's Doctrines design to do it like this. It's because of the easiness of DQL, it makes a diff on the changes posted. I tried to find a solution but couldn't find.

Comment: This has been my impression as well. Somehow, though, I feel there must (or should) be an idiomatic way to add to an entity's child collection without passing the full collection back and forth...